# React home page component not showing on github pages

Tags: react-router, github-pages

I struggled for hours trying to get my react app up to github pages and found I had to set the path for home component to the url homepage specified in the JSON used to deploy. Now however all the components show except for the home component. Any reason why this would be the case? If you need more code please let me know.

```
function Spa() {
  return (
    <HashRouter>
      <NavBar/>
      <UserContext.Provider value={{users:[{name:'abel',email:'abel@mit.edu',password:'secret',balance:100, loggedin: false}]}}>
        <div className="container" style={{padding: "20px"}}>
         <Routes>
          **<Route path="/bad_bank" element={<Home />} >**
            
            </Route>
          <Route path="/CreateAccount/" element={<CreateAccount/>} >
             
          </Route>
          <Route path="/login/" element={<Login/>}  >

          </Route>
          <Route path="/deposit/" element={<Deposit/>} >

          </Route>
          <Route path="/withdraw/" element={<Withdraw/>} >

          </Route>
          <Route path="/alldata/" element={<AllData/>} >

          </Route>
          </Routes>
        </div>
      </UserContext.Provider>      
    </HashRouter>
   
  );
}



root.render(<Spa/>);
```

Comment: Is it ***only*** the `"/bad_bank"` path that isn't rendering its `element`? Or is there some issue in the `Home` component? Try rendering `Home` on another path, and at the same time, try rendering different JSX on `"/bad_bank"`.

Comment: ok good idea ill try that, yes thats the only one not rendering

Comment: ok so home did render when i put it on another path so it must be a problem with the /bad_bank path.

Comment: Odd, it's not like `"/bad_bank"` is an invalid path value. Do you have any other server configurations or similar running in you rgithub?

Comment: sorry not sure what you mean by that

Comment: Do you have any custom server routing files that wold "hijack" the `"/bad_bank"` URL path external to your React app?